# Pandas column that depends on its previous value (row)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a 3rd column in my dataframe, which depends on both the new and existing columns in the *previous* row.

This new column should start at 0.

I would like my 3rd column to start at 0.

Its next value is its previous value plus `df.below_lo[i]` (if the previous value was 0).

If its previous value was 1, its next value is its previous value plus `df.above_hi[i]`.

I think I have two issues: how to initiate this 3rd column and how to make it dependent on itself.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

data = {'below_lo': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        'above_hi': [0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['pos'] = math.nan
df['pos'][0] = 0

for i in range(len(df.below_lo)):
    if df.pos[i] == 0:
        df.pos[i+1] = df.pos[i] + df.below_lo[i]
    if df.pos[i] == 1:
        df.pos[i+1] = df.pos[i] + df.above_hi[i]

print(df)
```

The desired output is:

```
    below_lo  above_hi  pos
0        0.0       0.0  0.0
1        1.0       0.0  0.0
2        0.0      -1.0  1.0
3        0.0       0.0  0.0
4        0.0      -1.0  0.0
5        0.0       0.0  0.0
6        0.0      -1.0  0.0
7        0.0       0.0  0.0
8        0.0       0.0  0.0
9        1.0       0.0  0.0
10       0.0       0.0  1.0
11       0.0       0.0  1.0
12       0.0       0.0  1.0
13       NaN       NaN  1.0
```

The above code produces the correct output, except I am also getting a few of these error messages:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

How do I clean this code up so that it runs without throwing this warning? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[0, 'pos'] = 0

for i in range(len(df.below_lo)):
    if df.loc[i, 'pos'] == 0:
        df.loc[i+1, 'pos'] = df.loc[i, 'pos'] + df.loc[i, 'below_lo']
    if df.loc[i, 'pos'] == 1:
        df.loc[i+1, 'pos'] = df.loc[i, 'pos'] + df.loc[i, 'above_hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate there is an accepted, and perfectly good, answer by @Michael O. already, but if you dislike iterating over rows as not-quite Pandas-esque, here is a solution without explicit looping over rows:

```
from functools import reduce
res = reduce(lambda d, _ : 
    d.fillna({'pos':d['pos'].shift(1) 
            + (d['pos'].shift(1)  == 0) * d['below_lo'] 
            + (d['pos'].shift(1)  == 1) * d['above_hi']}), 
        range(len(df)), df)
res
```

produces

```
      below_lo    above_hi    pos
--  ----------  ----------  -----
 0           0           0      0
 1           1           0      1
 2           0          -1      0
 3           0           0      0
 4           0          -1      0
 5           0           0      0
 6           0          -1      0
 7           0           0      0
 8           0           0      0
 9           1           0      1
10           0           0      1
11           0           0      1
12           0           0      1
```

It is, admittedly, somewhat less efficient and has a bit more obscure syntax. But it could be written on a single line (even if I split it over a few for clarity)!

The idea is that we can use `fillna(..)` function by passing the value, calculated from the previous value of 'pos' (hence `shift(1)`) and current values of 'below_lo' and 'above_hi'. The extra complication here is that this operation will only fill `NaN` with a non-NaN for the row just below the one with non-NaN value. Hence we need to apply this function repeatedly until all NaNs are filled, and this is where `reduce` comes into play

Comment: Are you saying that this solution is both slower and less clear than the for loop approach? What's the benefit of this solution?

Comment: @falsePockets as mentioned in the post (1) no explicit looping; (2) educational as in how to use `reduce` creatively; (3) shorter code

Comment: What's the benefit of no explicit looping? Usually in pandas if you replace a `for` loop with a pandas call, the loop is done in C, which is fast. But in this case the loop is still done in python, so it's slow. So what's the benefit of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works ***faster*** is

```py
df_ser['go_up'] = 0
df_ser['go_down'] = 0
df_ser.loc[(((df_ser["awake"] == 1) & (df_ser["awake"].shift() == 0) ), 'go_up'] = 1 # Go from 0 to 1
df_ser.loc[(((df_ser["awake"] == 0) & (df_ser["awake"].shift() == 1) ), 'go_down'] = 1 # Switch from 1 to 0
```

avoid using `range()`, pandas works at column level,
`.shift()` picks up immediate previous row